# showing similar value in x and y-axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matching, scatter

i have matrix as below;
from the calculation there will be some value that will be have same value to each other when plotting in graph (i used scatter plot),[image: redundant value when plotted]
the question here is how to know/identify which calculation is giving the matching data and can it be stored in the table. i have tried used find function in matlab but error occured.

```
A = [2/3 -1/3 -1/3;
    -1/3 2/3 -1/3;
    -1/3 -1/3 2/3];
B=[0 0 0;
    0 0 1;
    0 1 0;
    0 1 1;
    1 0 0;
    1 0 1;
    1 1 0;
    1 1 1];
d= [2/3 -1/3 -1/3];
q = [0 0.5773 -0.5773];
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    p1 =  A * B(1,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0a(i) = d*p1;
    qtransformation0a(i) = q*p1;
    p2 =  A * B(2,:)' -A * B(i,:)'
    dtransformation0b(i) = d*p2;
    qtransformation0b(i) = q*p2;
     p3 =  A * B(3,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0c(i) = d*p3;
    qtransformation0c(i) = q*p3;
    p4 =  A * B(4,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0d(i) = d*p4;
    qtransformation0d(i) = q*p4;
    p5 =  A * B(5,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0e(i) = d*p5;
    qtransformation0e(i) = q*p5;
    p6 =  A * B(6,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0f(i) = d*p6;
    qtransformation0f(i) = q*p6;
end
figure
 scatter(dtransformation0a,qtransformation0a,100,'b.')
hold on
scatter(dtransformation0b,qtransformation0b,100,'b.')
hold on
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "redundant" here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth means when the matlab multiply and plot the graph there will be at least 3 multiplication that give the same value of x-and y-axis. so my interest here is to find which multiplication that produce that.

Comment: @RoneyMichael can you help me with this. the solution you gave me before. cant work

Comment: @dan: I won't be notified unless I'm already active on the thread. I just happened to see this by chance. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @dan: I need to clarify something: say `(dtransformation0a, qtransformation0a)` is the set of points `PA`, and `(dtransformation0b, qtransformation0b)` is the set of points `PB`. Now I have observed that there are redundancies within `PA` and `PB` separately as well as redundancies between the two. For example, The point `(0,0)` occurs twice in `PA` and once in `PB`. Now, do you mean that it should only come once in `PA` and remain the same in `PB`?

Comment: @RoneyMichael i want to find all the same value. no matter either it is in PA or PB. as long as when it is put in graph it is giving the same dotted line at the same x-axis (dtransformation)and y axis (qtransformation).let say point (0,0) occurs twice in PA and once in PB so i want to know multiplication of what giving those point. im stuck. dont know what to do. i think it can be solve by using for-loops right?but how. thanks alot man

Comment: @RoneyMichael it didn't show where point (0,0) occurs.. it should occurs twice in PA and once in PB right?

Comment: @dan: It did. Now it should only occur once in `my_points`.

Comment: @RoneyMichael i have edit the question and attached a picture. thanks alot man..

Comment: @RoneyMichael if you refer to the picture above, it shows that point (0,0) have 7 dotted from different multiplication..so i want to find what those multiplication are... hehehe..maybe u misunderstanding my questions.

Comment: Ok, for that couldn't you just give conditionals within the loop? I'll attach code below.

Comment: @RoneyMichael thanks man..something similar like that.. but i need to re-alter it because from your code you already stated the points (0,0) but the problem is when i didnt know what are the points..let say if i have 2000 data... anyway the fprintf("dtransformation0a => (%f = %f * %f;)\n",dtransformation0a(i),d,p1); should replace with  fprintf('dtransformation0a => (%f = %f * %f;)\n',dtransformation0a(i),d,p1);

Comment: @dan: Ok. Happy to help. :) If you need further assistance, I'm willing to help if you can provide a simple, basic, example of what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to a MATLAB interpreter right now so I can't test it myself, but this should work:

```
A = [2/3 -1/3 -1/3;
    -1/3 2/3 -1/3;
    -1/3 -1/3 2/3];
B = [0 0 0;
    0 0 1;
    0 1 0;
    0 1 1;
    1 0 0;
    1 0 1;
    1 1 0;
    1 1 1];
d = [2/3 -1/3 -1/3];
q = [0 0.5773 -0.5773];
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    p1 =  A * B(1,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0a(i) = d*p1;
    qtransformation0a(i) = q*p1;
    p2 =  A * B(2,:)' -A * B(i,:)'
    dtransformation0b(i) = d*p2;
    qtransformation0b(i) = q*p2;
     p3 =  A * B(3,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0c(i) = d*p3;
    qtransformation0c(i) = q*p3;
    p4 =  A * B(4,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0d(i) = d*p4;
    qtransformation0d(i) = q*p4;
    p5 =  A * B(5,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0e(i) = d*p5;
    qtransformation0e(i) = q*p5;
    p6 =  A * B(6,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0f(i) = d*p6;
    qtransformation0f(i) = q*p6;
end

X = [dtransformation0a, dtransformation0b];    %Assuming dtransformation0a and dtransformation0b are row martices.
Y = [qtransformation0a, qtransformation0b];    %Assuming qtransformation0a and qtransformation0b are row martices.
my_points = [X';Y'];    %Each row of my_points will represent a particular point.
my_points = unique(my_points, 'rows');    %Get unique rows, hence points.

figure
scatter(my_points(:,1),my_points(:,2),100,'b.')
```

Let me know if you face any problem.

**

### EDIT!!

**

As per your requirement stated, what I understood was that you want to display those calculations which yield the value, say, `(0,0)`; if this is indeed what you want, you should be able to get it by replacing the loop part by:

```
my_point = [0, 0];
for i = 1:size(B,1)
    p1 =  A * B(1,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0a(i) = d*p1;
    qtransformation0a(i) = q*p1;
    p2 =  A * B(2,:)' -A * B(i,:)'
    dtransformation0b(i) = d*p2;
    qtransformation0b(i) = q*p2;
     p3 =  A * B(3,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0c(i) = d*p3;
    qtransformation0c(i) = q*p3;
    p4 =  A * B(4,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0d(i) = d*p4;
    qtransformation0d(i) = q*p4;
    p5 =  A * B(5,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0e(i) = d*p5;
    qtransformation0e(i) = q*p5;
    p6 =  A * B(6,:)' -A * B(i,:)';
    dtransformation0f(i) = d*p6;
    qtransformation0f(i) = q*p6;

    if(dtransformation0a(i)==my_point(1))
        fprintf("dtransformation0a => (%f = %f * %f;)\n",dtransformation0a(i),d,p1);
    end
    if(dtransformation0b(i)==my_point(1))
        fprintf("dtransformation0b => (%f = %f * %f;)\n",dtransformation0b(i),d,p2);
    end
    if(qtransformation0a(i)==my_point(2))
        fprintf("qtransformation0a => (%f = %f * %f;)\n",qtransformation0a(i),q,p1);
    end
    if(qtransformation0b(i)==my_point(2))
        fprintf("qtransformation0b => (%f = %f * %f;)\n",qtransformation0b(i),q,p2);
    end
end
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.